# fosuserbundle get error message on ovveriding loginaction

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I override a loginaction by using:

```
namespace PjDZ\UserBundle\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController as BaseController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class SecurityController extends BaseController {
    public function loginAction(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request)
    {
         $response   = parent::loginAction($request);

        //how can i get error message if exist from $response ??

        return $response;
    }
}
```

and i want to get the error message generated in main loginaction.
Thank you and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Which version of FOSUserBundle?

Comment: hummmm, I don't know :p
I downloaded it from: "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master"
hope can help you.

Comment: What do you really need to do? Maybe the new events are better: [Hooking into the controllers](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/controller_events.md)

Comment: In main loginAction() we generate an error message if authentification failure, I want to use this message in my overriding loginAction().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message lives in the request or the session. If you want to access it, simple copy the code from the [SecurityController](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/SecurityController.php#L25):

```
namespace PjDZ\UserBundle\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController as BaseController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

class SecurityController extends BaseController
{
    public function loginAction(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request)
    {
        /** @var $session \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session */
        $session = $request->getSession();

        // get the error if any
        if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } elseif (null !== $session && $session->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } else {
            $error = '';
        }

        if ($error) {
            $error = $error->getMessage();
        }

        // do something with the $error message!

        return parent::loginAction($request);;
    }
}
```

Take care, I removed the `$session->remove()` part, so the parent action is also able to obtain the error message from the session.

Comment: Whene i try this solution and I access to /login form, I have blank page.

Comment: Hmm, indents a php error. look in the error.log of your webserver.

Comment: Btw. I forgot to add the `$session` variable. Edited my answer.

Comment: After clearing cach, this is error I get:
ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "SecurityContext" from namespace "PjDZ\UserBundle\Controller" in C:\wamp\www\PagesJaunesDZ\src\PjDZ\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController.php line 24. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?

Comment: Yeah simple as that, forgot the `use` Statement after copying, you should fix this by yourself. Your homework ;)

Comment: Yeah I already fix it by calling : Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext; Thank you ;)